# NaNs comparing equal in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, nan, ieee-754, multidimensional-array

Consider the following script:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([np.nan], dtype=float)
b = np.array([np.nan], dtype=float)
print a == b

a = np.array([np.nan], dtype=object)
b = np.array([np.nan], dtype=object)
print a == b
```

On my machine this prints out

```
[False]
[ True]
```

The first case is clear ([as per IEEE-754](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565164/what-is-the-rationale-for-all-comparisons-returning-false-for-ieee754-nan-values)), but what's going on in the second case? Why are the two NaNs comparing equal?

Python 2.7.3, Numpy 1.6.1 on Darwin.

Comment: In the second case, all nan-objects are equal.

Comment: @Daniel: Empirically, that's what seems to be happening, but: (1) what's the rationale for violating IEEE-754? (2) is this documented somewhere?

Comment: A simple possibility is just that this is what `list` does: `x = [numpy.nan]; x == x #>>> True`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On newer versions of numpy you get this warning:

```
FutureWarning: numpy equal will not check object identity in the future. The comparison did not return the same result as suggested by the identity (`is`)) and will change.
```

my guess is that numpy is using `id` test as a shortcut, for `object` types before falling back to `__eq__` test, and since

```
>>> id(np.nan) == id(np.nan)
True
```

it returns true.

if you use `float('nan')` instead of `np.nan` the result would be different:

```
>>> a = np.array([np.nan], dtype=object)
>>> b = np.array([float('nan')], dtype=object)
>>> a == b
array([False], dtype=bool)
>>> id(np.nan) == id(float('nan'))
False
```

Comment: I like the hypothesis, thanks. I suppose it would not be unreasonable to characterise the behaviour as a bug.

Comment: Your example is faulty: `id(4.5)==id(float('4.5'))` is also `False`.